# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.toggleDrawer')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm setting up my drawer navigator with my stack navigator.

The menu button is supposed to trigger my drawer but whenever I press on it I'm getting this error.

I passed 'navigation' as input in App() and I have imported the drawer navigation library...not sure what's going on here

This is my App.js. The line with the error is at the end of the code

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { NavigationContainer , getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'; 
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'; 
import { DrawerContent} from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/navigation/DrawerContent'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'


import LoadingScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/LoadingScreen'
import WelcomeScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/WelcomeScreen'
import SignInScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/SignInScreen'
import SignUpScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/SignUpScreen'
import HomeScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/HomeScreen'
import MyGamesScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/MyGamesScreen'
import WishListScreen from '/Users/toxnd/Documents/MaisJogo/MaisJogoApp/screens/WishListScreen'


function getHeaderTitle(route) {

  const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Home';

  switch (routeName) {
    case 'Home':
      return 'Home';
    case 'Meus Jogos':
      return 'Meus Jogos';
    case 'Quero Jogar':
      return 'Quero Jogar';
    }
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Home({ navigation, route }) {
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({ headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route) });
  }, [navigation, route]);

  return (
    
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} /> }>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name='Meus Jogos'
        component={MyGamesScreen}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name='Quero Jogar'
        component={WishListScreen}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>

    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = ({navigation}) => {

  return (
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Loading"
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#BB2CD9',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        }}>
        
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
              name='Loading' component={LoadingScreen} />
          
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
              name='Welcome' component={WelcomeScreen} />
          
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{headerShown: false}}
              name="Sign In" component={SignInScreen} />
          
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        name='Sign Up' component={SignUpScreen} /> 

        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button name='menu' size={25}
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
              />
            )
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue but I did some quick fix which is not verified.

```
import { getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute } from '@react-navigation/native' // undefined

export default (route) => {
    if(route.state && route.state.routeNames.length > 1){
        return route.state.routeNames.slice(-1)[0]
    }else{
        return
    }
}
```

Use it at your own risk